# Lookup SQL table values using sys.columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-like, dynamic-sql, lookup-tables

So let's say I have data from supermarkets which tell me how many fruits of each type have sold and I want to know the total number of red and green fruit sold per supermarket. I have 3 tables:

Table 1 is a temporary table which shows how many fruits sold per supermarket and has values assigned to variable column names:

```
╔═══════╦════════╦════════╗
║ Apple ║ Banana ║ Cherry ║
╠═══════╬════════╬════════╣
║     1 ║      5 ║      7 ║
║     3 ║      0 ║      4 ║
╚═══════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Table 2 is a permanent table with my desired column names in the first column and what texts I need it to lookup (e.g. I don't want yellow fruit so I don't want Banana's values to be imported):

```
╔═══════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ Colour║  Lookup 1  ║ Lookup 2 ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║ Red   ║ Apple      ║ Cherry   ║
║ Green ║ Watermelon ║ Kiwi     ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

Table 3 is my final permenant table with my desired columns and values in it:

```
╔═════════════╦═════╦═══════╗
║ Supermarket ║ Red ║ Green ║
╠═════════════╬═════╬═══════╣
║ Temco       ║   6 ║     8 ║
║ ASPA        ║   2 ║     4 ║
║ Sansbrys    ║   2 ║     1 ║
║ Morris      ║   5 ║     3 ║
╚═════════════╩═════╩═══════╝
```

What's the best way of looking up the column names in table 1 using the values in table 2 and then insert the values that I want into table 3?

I have got to this stage which sort of does the second half of the process without using the lookup table 2 but completely stuck with the first half:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max),
        @Columns nvarchar(2000)
declare @table nvarchar(256) = '[etl].[Temco]'
truncate table etl.Supermarkets
SELECT @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ', ', '') + quotename(column_name)
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name= 'Temco' and (column_name like '%Apple%' OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Cherry%')
PRINT @Columns
set @Columns = left(@Columns,len(@Columns)-1) -- remove trailing comma
set @sql = ' insert into [etl].[Supermarkets]
 ([Red])
 SELECT ' + @Columns + '] from  ' +@table+' '
PRINT @sql
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@table nvarchar(256)',
@table = @table
```

Comment: The best solution would be to normalize table1 into a known structure. The seems like a table with 3 columns to me (SupermarketID, Fruit, QuantitySold) instead of the denormalized nightmare you are working with.  You seem to have the same normalization problem with Table2.

Comment: @SeanLange That would be ideal but I can't control the table I get in Table 1 and so I need a way to extract only certain columns using the lookup table.

Comment: Well your lookup table is just as bad. The reason you are struggling here is the tables are not normalized. Then you have your final third table which is a continuation of poorly designed tables. This is nothing short of a herculean effort to overcome a poor design. If the ddl is done correctly, retrieving the data is simple. Since it seems you can't fix the disastrous structures you are going to have to provide us some details about the tables.